# Perl: Using Config::General to write into file - missing equal to sign

Tags: perl

I am using the Perl `Config::General` module to read and write a config file.

My input config file looks like this:

```
<foo>
    key1 = val1
    key2 = val2
</foo>
```

but after making changes when I write this config into a file using `$conf->save_file` call, it produces something like this

```
<foo>
   key1 val3
   key2 val4
</foo>
```

Any idea how to retain the "=" sign? My config file needs to be user-readable - this format is still readable but ideally I want to retain the "=" sign since the concerned users are non-technical sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can* use the [`-StoreDelimiter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General#StoreDelimiter) option to `new`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::General;

my %settings = (
    foo => {
        key1 => 'val1',
        key2 => 'val2'
    }
);

my $conf = Config::General->new(-StoreDelimiter => ' = ');
$conf->save_file('settings.conf', \%settings);
```

Output:

```
<foo>
    key2 = val2
    key1 = val1
</foo>
```

---

* According to the documentation, this shouldn't work; if `-SplitPolicy` is set to `guess` (the default) or `whitespace`, the output delimiter should be set to three spaces. So this is either an exploit or the documentation is wrong; I've submitted a [trouble report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=106642) to the module author.

You would probably be better off using the documented solution of

```
-SplitPolicy => 'equalsign'
```

that [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) and [BaZZiliO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5215544/bazzilio) gave (although this forces you to use equal signs everywhere in config files that you *read* as well as write, instead of the default behavior that allows either spaces or equal signs).

Comment: @KedarJoshi This behavior isn't documented (at least, not clearly). I've submitted a trouble report to the author; this could just be an undocumented/poorly documented feature, or it could be a bug in the code, in which case it could be removed in a future release. Borodin and BaZZiliO's solution might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the option

```
'-SplitPolicy' => 'equalsign'
```

Comment: Might be good to note that this also forces you to use an equal sign as a delimiter everywhere when *reading* config files, instead of the default policy of allowing either spaces or equal signs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set -SplitPolicy to 'equalsign'

Read the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General/General.pm#SUBROUTINES/METHODS), which says this

> You can influence the way how Config::General decides which part of a line in a config file is the key and which one is the value. By default it tries its best to guess. That means you can mix equalsign assignments and whitespace assignments.
>
> However, sometime you may wish to make it more strictly for some reason. In this case you can set -SplitPolicy. The possible values are: 'guess' which is the default, 'whitespace' which causes the module to split by whitespace, 'equalsign' which causes it to split strictly by equal sign, or 'custom'. In the latter case you must also set -SplitDelimiter to some regular expression of your choice. For example: